# Iterating through keys of Immutable Map in React

Tags: dictionary, reactjs, immutability

What is a good practice for handling iteration through an Immutable.js Map object? This works:

```
{stocks.map((stock,key)=>{
    return ( <h3>{key}</h3> )
})}
```

but gives the warning in the console "warning.js:45 Warning: Using Maps as children is not yet fully supported. It is an experimental feature that might be removed. Convert it to a sequence / iterable of keyed ReactElements instead."

This has been discussed before, and this link suggests some strategies https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/667 but they seem clunky to me. Like:

```
posts.entrySeq().map(o => 
     <Post value={o[1]} key={o[0]} />
)
```

works but is clunky feeling. Is there a more natural way of doing this?

Comment: I ran into the same problem recently and ended up using `entrySeq()` as well. I think the only other alternative would be to use `toJS()` which is not less clunky and probably less performant.

Comment: Thanks for the input

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you asked this question, a better solution has been posted on the github issue you reference. @vinnymac suggests:

```
posts.entrySeq().map( ([key, value]) => 
  <Post key={key} value={value} />
)
```

this works well because `entrySeq()` returns a Sequence of key/value tuples, which you can then destructure in the params of the `.map()` callback.

**edit** I see now that you are only asking for the keys. In that case use `keySeq()` if you want to use ImmutableJS `map()` or `keys()` if you want to use ES6 `map()`

Answer (score 2):

Why not `stock.keys()`? As it returns an ES6 iterator, you'll need to cast it to an array for it to work in older JS versions: `Array.from(stock.keys())`

```js
let zoo = Immutable.fromJS({ 'dog': 1, 'cat': 2 })

zoo.keys().map((name, index) => <Animal name={ name } key={ index } />)
```

Notice that I avoided `key` as a variable and then passed the `index` value as `key` to the children component, this is because react needs references to dynamically created components so it can handle them correctly within its VirtualDOM. Read more about React's [Dynamic Children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html).

Answer (score 0):

Using Immutable Map's reduce method is a more direct approach. Since react expects an array so setting initial value of empty array and pushing jsx into it solves the issue. Works for immutable List as well.

```
{
   stocks.reduce((jsxArray, stock, index) => {
      jsxArray.push(
        <h3 key={index}>{index}</h3>,
      )
      return jsxArray;
   }, [])
}
```